# Coda Slider not displaying images during animation

Tags: javascript, wordpress, conflict, coda-slider

I got a Coda Slider working retrieving data from posts, but now that I've installed other plugins to the site it started failing to display images while the transition is taking place.

http://poesis.savvy-studio.net/

I know that it might be a javascript conflict but I dont know where to start, hope you guys might know where to look at.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to identify which plugin is conflicting, this is just a trial and error process, remove them one at a time until you get results.

I am going to assume you are getting no console errors at this point so the best thing you can do is pin down the plugin then look for more specific information. Currently your question is extremely vague...

Comment: The plugin that is conflicting is called Events Manager, and yeap, no console warnings so far. Thank you for having a look.

Comment: You should read the comment made by Vian Esterhuizen, you should never have multiple DOM elements using the same ID, ID is unique, class is intended for multiple instances of the same element

Comment: Thanks again for the advice. I should be more carefull with that. But even after removing the ID the conflict remains.